# AfterMethod cannot be resolved to a type error?

Tags: testng

why cannot be assign @AfterMethod testNG annotation to AfterMethod()?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems your import is wrong.  Choose the second option from the quick fixes.

Comment: well the point here is.. if we are having the method name same as that of the annotation before importing the package we will not get the right package name in the sub-menu to import it is only after we change the name of the method to another from that of the annotation name we will be in a position to import..

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean to say.  The @AfterMethod is an annotation from the testng package hierarchy.  If you are defining a same named method then that is in your project's package hierarch - how does it matter what is the name of your method as long as the package hierarchy is different.

Comment: it should not matter, but that is the error happening here. Before importing the aftermethod package if we name a method as AfterMethod and then give an another to it as @AfterMethod then it is throwing up the error, the error goes away when we change the name of the method in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import below code in your class before add @AfterMethod annotation in code.
"import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;".

Kindly check more details on below link[Import class for Annotations](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_execution_procedure.htm)